# Issue About Facebook SDK. Is Facebook Image URL Change Each Login ? How To Get Image URL and Facebook ID From Facebook SDK 7.9 In Unity C#?

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I have searching some thread about get url from facebok sdk. But still i don't understand how it work. And i doubt it is same with Newest Facebook SDK 7.9.

Is the URL Facebook Image Always same each login ? Or it will change ?. If it is always same then i can store it to the database and i can call as i want without no need to get the url again.

and

In the facebook SDK 7.9 i can't find any function that call facebook ID. Is FB.AppId is the facebook user ID ?

Is the Facebook ID always same each login ?

I need to display all picture facebook in the Leaderboards. So i need a image url from facebook.

What is the best way to do it ?

How to retrieve image url that can be save to the database ?

or Is there anything If we can get the Facebook ID or we have the Facebook ID we can call the Image URL from the facebook ID even we are not login ?

Can someone explain to me ?

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: I assume you are talking about the profile image of the user here? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture // Facebook CDN URLs are to be considered transient, they can change over time, and once working URLs can become invalid. So using the API call that responds with an automatic redirect is the easiest thing to do. If you want to store images on your end, then it would be your responsibility to keep them up to date, if the user chooses a new profile picture or removes an existing one.

Comment: Okay. I see that you understand my question. Then how to get the Image file ? I need to save it to the cloud. It is for use to show the profile picture at leaderboard.

Comment: Why do you need to save it to the cloud? Where and how do you want to display it? Why is the API URL that will automatically redirect to the CDN location not enough?

Comment: If save to cloud then I can display It at leaderboard. Leaderboard Have a list of facebook player. So i have want to display all leaderboard player with profile picture then i need to save every player picture image when login to back end database. If want to display the current profile picture then it is enough just using the API URL.

Comment: Why would you show outdated profile pictures in the first place? Facebook Platform Policy demands that you keep such data up-to-date - which in regard to profile pictures means, show the _current_ one for the user, and not one they have used in the past, and which they might even have removed by now.

Comment: I don't know how to show the updated profile picture. As we can only show display picture when login using : FB.API("/me/picture?redirect=false", HttpMethod.GET, ProfilePhotoCallback); .In Leaderboard all the player data is loaded from the database. So how to show the current display picture if player is not login ?

Comment: Use the user id instead of `me`...?

Comment: It look like there is a enlighten in here. How to get the user id in facebook sdk ?. I have try see there is no call user id. If i got the user id i can know save the user id to database. And now i can display it.

Comment: Seriously …? That is one of the most basic things there is ... You can call `/me` with the user’s access token, and you get their id … or you can as well get it directly from the access token after login, as the _basic example_ (did you even bother to look at these before asking?) here shows: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/examples#login

Comment: Yeah.. Sorry i just not read it. I don't know if it could be call with this : Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.UserId. I have try find it. But don't know it is refer to the accessToken. Thank You Very Much @CBroe. You are my Mentor. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this code for retrieving the current Profile Picture :

```
FB.API("/me/picture?redirect=false", HttpMethod.GET, ProfilePhotoCallback);

private void ProfilePhotoCallback (IGraphResult result)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error) && !result.Cancelled) {
            IDictionary data = result.ResultDictionary["data"] as IDictionary;
            string photoURL = data["url"] as string;

            StartCoroutine(fetchProfilePic(photoURL));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator fetchProfilePic (string url) {
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        this.profilePic = www.texture;

        //Construct a new Sprite
        Sprite sprites = new Sprite();     

        //Create a new sprite using the Texture2D from the url. 
        //Note that the 400 parameter is the width and height. 
        //Adjust accordingly

        sprite = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, 50 ,50), Vector2.zero);  
        sprites = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, 50 ,50), Vector2.zero);  

    }
```

and to Retriving other player profile picture you must know the user id first.

Here is the code to check the user id :

```
Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.UserId
```

After that use :

```
FB.API ("/" + userid + "/picture?redirect=false", HttpMethod.GET, ProfilePhotoCallback);
```

To retrive selected user id profile picture.